# Accent insensitive ADO.NET dataset relations

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, dataset, collation, diacritics

Is there any way to make a relation in a ADO.NET dataset accent insensitive?

I am working with a system that uses som legacy datastructures that are used from a .net application. In the datastructure there are two related tables. The relation is between two text fields containing names. The issue is that the names can differ when it comes to accents in  the ends of the relation. So you can have "Rosen" in one table and in the related it could be "Rosén" the two variants of the name should be considered to be the same. In SQL Server you can achieve this by setting the collation of the columns to be one of the Accent insensitive versions i.e Finnish_swedish_CI_AI

Pleas I need help with this. I hope someone have some sort of solution.